# How to prevent IE from opening my page in compatibility mode?

Tags: html, jsp, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

I have this html/jsp page:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html ...
</html>
```

which, for some reason, is opened by default in compatibility mode on IE (in my case version 10) and this messes up everything as it just does not understand some modern constructs present in libraries such as angularjs.
By opening developer's tools and changing the view mode to "standard IE" everything fixes up and my web application works fine.

So, what's wrong with this header? Is there a way to force IE to open my page in normal mode?

This question is more or less the same of this one, I know that:
[Why Does IE-8 push the view to Compact/Compatibility view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945866/why-does-ie-8-push-the-view-to-compact-compatibility-view)

but I don't want to force my user to open tools and set options like correct marked answer suggests: most of them are just ignorant, many of them have developers tools disabled on their company's PC.
In the end just want to see where's the problem with my web application and make so that IE accepts it as a normal page.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275356/ie-compatibility-mode-x-ua-compatible-tag-edge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

insert meta tag in header HTML:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>
```

The "edge" forces standards mode (or latest rendering engine) in IE.

To force IE8 to standard mode.

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=8">
```